# How to obtain the coordinates of a float (figure, table, etc..) in Latex

Tags: latex

I have a specific problem: I want to place a chart in my latex document as a pdf figure, and the legend as separate figure outside the chart (in order to do not cover the information in the chart).
In order to do that I've been using the following trick:

```
\begin{textblock}{2}(12,7.02)
    \includegraphics[scale=.3]{graphics/ch5_cl_legend2.pdf}
\end{textblock}
```

In this way I can decide the exact position of the legend.

The problem is that if I add new text before the chart, or in general the chart changes the position, the legend will stay in the position I specified, therefore I have to change it manually.

I would like to obtain the position of the primary figure, the chart, and store it in a variable; then use this variable plus some constant offsets to specify the position of the second figure, the legend.

I thought that doing something like this would hook the legend to the chart, but it didn't:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{graphics/ch5_s0_fh.pdf}
    \begin{textblock}{2}(12,7.02)
        \includegraphics[scale=.3]{graphics/ch5_cl_legend2.pdf}
    \end{textblock}
    \vspace{-0.15cm}
    \caption{mycaption}
    \label{fig:ch5_s0_s_fh}
    \vspace{-0.3cm}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions you may have, they'll be very appreciated!
G.